# Transmit The Images Numpy Array Faster in Python

Tags: python, flask, image-processing, deep-learning, streaming

Currently, I've developed a simple Web Application using Flask Framework. The main language which I am using is Python.

I'm supposing that I have 2 primary files that are Flask Server and Flask Client.

The Flask Server will initialize a Deep Learning Model (e.g Object detection).

The Flask Client will grab frames from the camera source and send the frames to Flask Server to get the bounding boxes of objects.

My question here is if the video frames are too large (4k resolution). It will take a lot of time to transfer the frames. The time would be 200 ms for only one frame.

I want to make a real-time application on the client-side. Has anyone known the good approach for passing frames from this Python application to another Python application? I only consider the progress is happening in the local network (at the same computer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.8 has exactly the thing for you - [Shared Memory](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html). You can create a lump of shared memory and access it from independent Python processes on the same machine. I made a very simple example with a single frame of 4k UHD video (3840x2160) shared between 2 separate Python processes. So, start this one (`shmemA.py`) in one Terminal, preferably in IPython:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

# Define dimensions of 4k video
w, h = 3840, 2160

# Create a named SharedMemory object
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, name="SharedVideoBuffer", size=w*h*3)

# Create a Numpy array backed by that SharedMemory
im = np.ndarray((h,w,3), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=shm.buf)

# Fill that array such that the other process can see it
im[:] = 32
```

And start this (`shmemB.py`) in a separate Terminal afterwards:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

# Define dimensions of 4k video
w, h = 3840, 2160

# Attach to existing SharedMemory created by our buddy
existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='SharedVideoBuffer')

# Create Numpy array backed by that SharedMemory
im = np.ndarray((h,w,3), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
```

You can now time how long it takes to write from the first process to the second with:

```
%timeit im[:]=56
776 µs ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And you can see it takes 776 microseconds to transmit a 4K frame between the processes, so it could achieve over 1,000 fps.

In your scenario, you might consider double-buffering (i.e. ping-ponging) between two buffers so that one process is writing the second while the other is reading the first. So you would create 2 shared memory buffers (or a single one twice the size) and alternate between them. You could use a `multiprocessing Queue` between the two processes to tell the reader which buffer has just been filled.

**Keywords**: Python, shared memory, SharedMemory, fast IPC, ping-pong, double-buffered, fast image transfer.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your solution. I've found out another approach that could be applied is memory-mapped files in Python. The idea behind the memory-mapped file is so simple. Firstly, we define a virtual file, set the size of the file to be the same at the frame. Process A (Python file A) will read the frames from a video source and write to that file. Process B (another file B) will go that location of file in memory and read out the bytes. The whole process is above 20 milliseconds. I think your solution is the fastest one I've seen. That's so impressive with 1000 FPS for 4k video.

Comment: Btw, multiprocessing Queue is similar to from queue import Queue? I think these queues can be useful when we are working in the same file? If 2 queues are created in separate Python files, it would be considered as 2 different objects. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you in advance. @Mark Setchell

Comment: I think you'd have to start your 2 processes from a common parent to send *multiprocessing.queue* messages between them. Someone please ping me if I am wrong. So you'd probably use a socket (or a SYSV, **zeromq**, or **MQTT** message) between them to coordinate.